How does DC converter switching cause broadband noise in this case?
As per Source1:
"a broadband disturbance is defined as an electromagnetic disturbance which has a bandwidth greater than that of a particular measuring apparatus, receiver or susceptible device.”

As per Source2, the broadband noise is generated due to DC/DC converter switching (3MHz and its harmonics). Since the resolution bandwidth is 30kHz, wouldn't the converter switching harmonics be considered as narrow band?
The same site at a different link mentions
"Note that by reducing the RBW way down to 1 kHz or so, you’ll be able to start resolving the harmonics from DC-DC converters or other switching power supplies. You’ll see that the signals are actually narrowband!"
Why do we need to reduce the RBW to 1kHz when the converter switching harmonics are spaced by 100s of kHz?

I agree with you, for some reason "DC-DC converter broadband noise" became commonplace phrase, and it is really annoying. I guess their (wrong) reasoning is that such a plot vast-range of frequency (like 1.5 GHz here) and use of MaxHold (like here), makes it LOOK like broadband signal compared to some high frequency clock signal (like 25 MHz here).
I also agree that reducing RBW down to 1 kHz is not necessary, even 30 kHz setting used here would show switching harmonics in the low-frequency range, say up to 30 MHz, for every "normal" DC-DC converter with switching frequency of 60 kHz and higher.
